# AWS SES VerifyEmailIdentity with Lightsail

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to use SES VerifyEmailIdentity in Python. It works totally fine on my local system however when we host on Lightsail instance the following error comes:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the VerifyEmailIdentity operation: User: arn:aws:sts::480862114276:assumed-role/AmazonLightsailInstanceRole/i-0e2s3ff15c45e0eb1 is not authorized to perform: ses:VerifyEmailIdentity because no identity-based policy allows the ses:VerifyEmailIdentity action

Python code working on localhost but having above error when hosted on Lightsail

```
import boto3

ses_client = boto3.client('ses', region_name='ap-south-1')  

def verify_email_address(email):
    response = ses_client.verify_email_identity(EmailAddress=email)
    return response
```

I tried but there is no way to attach a role to Lightsail instance in AWS through which i can attach permission. Expected result is just it works fine as on local and send email to intended address for verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you can (edit: mistake here, with which my explanation doesn't make any sense, wanted to write **can't** here) configure a role with which the LightSail instance is run, I suggest you create an IAM user and attach a role which would have sufficient permissions and pass the user credentials to the client:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN
)
```

Comment: AWS dont allow to attach role to lightsail instance like it allows for ec2

Comment: My mistake, I wanted to write `... can't configure`

Comment: If neither i can attach nor i can configure how it would work? Can you give some guide in detail? I am already using root account keys

Comment: Well I'm not sure if I understand the question here but the error is pretty clear, that you're trying to send the email with the assumed `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole` role. You need to create an IAM user and attach permissions to that user and use the users access keys.

Comment: How its working from my localhost in that case?

Comment: Well in localhost as you've said you're using "root account keys" (assuming an admin or role) rather than using a user with `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole`.

Comment: Keys are same in both case

Comment: But the role is not.